# Disable events triggered on HTML <SELECT> control

Tags: html, javascript, html-select

Is there a way to capture the events triggered on HTML controls before they are forwarded for default (generic) handling by the control itself. In my case, I want to prevent a  element dropdown to open when a user clicks on the control. e.g. On this user click, OnClick() event gets fired and is handled by the default control which open the dropdown. I want to stop this from happening.

Can I attach a custom function to this event and redirect the event handling to this one instead of the default code that opens the dropdown?

Thanks

Comment: You want that custom function to be executed onload event of that dropdown..

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905464/html-select-dropdown/1905474#1905474 as it is asking a pretty much identical question.

Answer (score 3):

onclick,onmousedown and onmouseup will not help you to prevent the selectbox from opening. I'm not asking why you want to do that, but if you really can't use any other solution, like for example (changing selectbox to the readonly inputbox), then, you can try the next solution.

One way to prevent the box from opening, is to create an overlay container, which will block the the focusable area of the select. This can be achived by placing the div after the selectbox and givving it the sizes and the position of the selectbox.

```
<div style="position:relative;">
    <select style="width:100px;height:30px">
        <option>hello</option> 
    </select>
    <div style="position:absolute;
          left:0;
          top:0;
          width:100px;
          height:30px;
          z-index:2;
          background-color:black;
          opacity:0;filter:Alpha(Opacity='0');"
    ></div>
</div>
```

Event then, it will work only for IE >= 7. Not for IE6, cause selectboxes in IE6 are strange( maybe you can try to fix IE6 with some iframe hack);

Comment: select boxes are "windowed" objects in IE6 and therefore appear on a different rendering plane, in front of the "windowless" rendering plane. Placing them inside an iframe might work.

Comment: Also, by blocking the "focusable area" of the select box, you are disabling the natural hover style of the element which would be an undesirable effect in my opinion.

Comment: @Andy E: You can delegate focus to the select, by dispatching onclick event of the div.

Comment: @nemisj: but you can't delegate hover.

Comment: @Andy E: You can set class on the selectbox, when onmouseover event triggers on the overlay,  (something like SelectBox_Hover) and style it by using CSS

Comment: @nemisj wow! it's working great. Exactly what I want it. Thanks a lot ! Just one suggestion which I have made in my solutions is that I have set height  = 100% and width = 100%. so it's cover whole select box.

Answer (score 3):

Fairly old question with some good suggestions, but none seem to directly answer the original question. In case anybody out there is wondering, I believe the OP was wanting to keep the visual appearance of the system/browser select element, but use his own custom drop-down menu instead of the system/browser drop-down menu.

In this case, the onclick event will occur too late for you to stop the actual drop-down menu from displaying. What you want to do is bind to the mousedown event, and prevent the event from propagating to the default behavior:

```
document.getElementById('my_select_id').onmousedown = function(event) {
   // ... do something here...perhaps display your own custom menu, an advanced selection chooser, focus another element, display a message, or some other custom handling.
   event.preventDefault(); // This prevents the drop-down menu from displaying
}
```

Notes:

- Replacing the drop-down with a custom-designed element (as suggested by others) isn't always an option. In some cases, you'll end up either having to completely omit default/system drop-downs from your site (in favor of a custom-designed element), or you have to live with a mismatch in visual appearance due to browser/system/theme differences (unless you feel like designing the custom element to match every conceivable visual aesthetic/theme.)
- Disabling the drop-down will not work, as it will prevent the event handlers from firing.
- Using optgroups will still allow the drop-down menu to be displayed.
- Replacing the drop-down with an empty version will still display an empty drop-down menu.

Answer (score 1):

*This is the answer I gave on another, similar question.*

This works great for me in IE and Chrome, there's no flicker or anything:

**html**

```
<select id="MySelect"><option>Hello</option></select>
```

**js**

```
MySelect.onmousedown = function ()
{
    window.setTimeout(function () 
    { 
        //- An immediate blur, then refocus stops the options from being displayed
        this.blur();
        this.focus();
        //- so now we run our custom function
        runOtherFunctionInstead(); 
    },0);
}
```

Make sure the js runs after the select element has been parse by placing it in an onload or ondocumentready or a script block after the select element.  Haven't tried it in Firefox or Opera.  Assumedly it would work in Safari, though.

**EDIT**
As suggested in the comments, the popup will still appear for a double click in IE (all versions). This is due to [a bug](http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/2008/01/bug-263-beware-of-doubleclick-in-ie.html) where the mousedown event doesn't fire for the second click (whoops).  You can quickly hide the options again by using the blur, focus method in the `ondblclick` event and if this method works in Firefox and Safari, I still think it's the best solution considering most people don't double click select boxes.

Comment: @nemsj: are you talking about a double-click or two seperate clicks?

Comment: both, with doubleclick it shows selection and in separate clicks also. Maybe i just have some really old version of IE6, i do not know.

Comment: @nemisj: I can repro in IE6 & IE8 for doubleclick but not two seperate clicks (maybe you have your double-click delay rate on high?), but I still think this is the best option at least for browsers that don't have the same bug - see the updates in my answer.

Comment: @Andy E: It is indeed a best solution for IE, so +1

Answer (score 1):

you need to set selectbox to be onload disabled: `disabled="disabled"`

Comment: then the onclick functions don't fire.