# prevent default behavior for a combobox and chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, focus, blur

I am trying to do, that when clicking on a combobox, the list should open, but instead a alert should pop up.

I have this code:

```
$('select').focus(function() {
    this.blur();
    window.focus();
});   

$('select').click(function(){
    alert('Clicked but did not open');
});
```

This works fine in FF, but doesnt work in chrome,

Any idea why?

Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/adc9M/17/)

```
$('select').click(function() {
    this.blur();
    window.focus();
    return false;
});
```

Adding return false works

Comment: Thank you, now it works in chrome but in FF it doesnt... any idea??

Comment: @Ovi try with the click event (see the new demo)

Comment: I only have FF 5... idk how to test it in 4 :(

Comment: Yes it does :( what exactly happens when you try it?

Comment: Ok, now it works in FF, but in chrome, the list opens, same prob i the beginning.., your demo works fine cuz it opens the list and then closes it right away, in my site it opens and it stays...

Answer (score 2):

To prevent the event from bubbling up you should use [`preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) for cross-browser compatibility.

```
$('select').mousedown(function(e) {
    this.blur();
    window.focus();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Never mind. Just e.preventDefault() by itself works in Firefox (21.0). It was only when I had a call to focus() in my mousedown handler that it still opened the select...

Answer (score 1):

Doing

```
$('select').mousedown(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

works in Chrome, IE 9 (not 8), and Opera (at least version 11.61, which is the one I have installed). It doesn't work in Firefox, don't know why. However, the blur on the element and the focus on the window don't work for me ever, neither in mousedown nor on click.

Inspired by an answer that got downvoted twice here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905464/html-select-dropdown), I came up with this little variation (the original makes the whole window flicker, it's a tad hideous):

```
$('select').mousedown(function(event) { 
   var $select = this;
   window.setTimeout(function () {          
      $select.blur();
      $select.focus();
      //do whatever like alert("This message");
   },0);        
   event.preventDefault();
   return false;
});
```

Now, for FF (I have version 10) and IE < 9, this means a slight flicker, as the dropdown actually opens to close right after, but preventDefault is there to make it work well in every other modern browser. Select is evil, I don't think there's a good cross-browser way to control whether the dropdown shows or not. Return false should do something according to the rumors on the Internet, so I left it there, may be it does work in older browsers.

P.S.: In your question you meant "[...] the list should **not** open, but instead [...]", right?